# How do prove that there is a vertex with degree less than 6 in a disconnected planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

As we all know, in every planar graph, connected or disconnected, there is at least a vertex $v$ with $deg(v) \leq 5$. (Even we can prove that there are at least ***two*** of such vertices.)

But, as I looked for a proof to this simple fact, I saw that all proofs rely on the fact that in every planar graph $e \leq 3v - 6$. But isn't this formula applicable only to connected graphs?

Comment: If the graph is not connected, pick 1 connected component and apply the rest of the proof. In fact, if your condition that $e\leq 3v-6$ holds for all connected components, then it holds for all graphs. Equality may not be possible, but that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G = (V,E)$ is a non-connected planar graph, add edges to make $G' = (V, E \uplus E')$ connected and planar, this is always possible (use induction on the number of connected components). Then 
$$ |E| \le |E \uplus E'| \le 3|V| - 6. $$

Comment: Simple, elegant, understandable and smart.
Much thanks.